# Take attribute when available, otherwise element

Tags: xml, xslt

I am processing an XML file with XSLT and I would like to get a list of properties per item with the following attributes:

- If attribute *aaa* is set, take the value of the attribute
- If attribute *aaa* is not set, take the value of the element
- From resulting set, only take distinct values

Here is an example XML

```
<items>
    <item>
        <properties>
            <property aaa="">pA</property>
            <property aaa="pB">pC</property>
            <property aaa="pA">pA</property>
        </properties>
    </item>
    <item>
        <properties>
            <property aaa="">pD</property>
            <property aaa="pE">pF</property>
        </properties>
    </item>
</items>
```

Now this is how I tried to achieve it:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/items/item">
    <xsl:for-each select="distinct-values(properties/property/@aaa | properties/property)[not(. = '')]"><xsl:value-of select="."/>#</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

The attribute *aaa* is always there, just sometime it is empty. The problem I have is, that if the attribute and the element are both set, they will both appear in the set. I only want the attribute to appear. So for the above XML, the correct solution would be

```
pA#pB#
pD#pE#
```

what my code gives me instead is

```
pA#pB#pC#
pD#pE#pF#
```

Is is possible to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you're using `distinct-values` suggests you are working in XSLT 2.0, so you can do it with a combination of the XPath 2.0 `for` and `if` constructs:

```
distinct-values(
    for $prop in properties/property
    return if ($prop/@aaa != '') then $prop/@aaa else $prop
)
```